# Material UI listen scroll on table (React)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a table with a body size fixed as explained in the Material UI.
I would like to listen to the scroll event of the table in order to load more rows.

Which is the best approach to listen to this scroll?

Answer (score 2):

Tried the first solution which didn't work with my implementation.

I got this working using material-ui@0.17.1 and React@15.4.2:

Create a table element and set the ref to a name:

```
<Table>
    ...
    <TableBody ref="table-body">
        ...
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

In componentDidMount, find the DOMNode using ReactDOM.findDOMNode:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let tableBodyNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["table-body"]).parentNode.parentNode;

    tableBodyNode.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

This will give you the scroll event of the table.

Comment: Is kind of weird the way we are handling this scroll listeners with parentNode.parentNode I remember I ended up using https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic but still not a good solution to fix this problem.

Comment: don't forget to remove the event listener in `componentWillUnmount()`

Answer (score 1):

This is not straightforward and perhaps material-ui's Table is not the best suited for your requirements. You may want to take a look at some infinite-scrolling components, like react-infinite or react-list.

That being said, I experimented a bit and came up with this method of intercepting the scroll event in material-ui's TableBody.

First, capture a reference to the scrollable div that your table's body is contained in (its grandparent element in this case):

```
<Table height={200}>
  ...
  <TableBody
    ref={ref => { this.viewport = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref).parentNode.parentNode; } }>
  ...
```

then, in componentDidMount(), add an event listener for the onscroll event to the scrollable div:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.viewport.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there way to scroll to bottom of the rows? I just tried to tweak your solution to set scrollTop. But it gave me the warning that `Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null`.